# ArrayFormula + Countifs

Tags: google-sheets

**Sheet 1**

```
        A           B         C . . .
1 STUDENT NAME   LEC. ID    GRADE
2 JOHN            123abc      A
3 SARAH           345def      B+
4 RAHUL           123abc      B+
.
.
.
```

**Sheet 2**

```
   A            B      C   D   E   F  G   H   I  J   K   L   M . . .
1 LEC. NAME  LEC. ID   A   B+  B-  B  B-  C+  C  C-  D   E   F
2 MARK       123abc    1   1
3 JEAN       123def        1
.
.
.
```

I need to count based on LEC. ID and GRADE in Sheet 1 and display it in Sheet 2. Is anyone know how to use ArrayFormula and countifs to do this.

I need to insert the formula at C1, D1, . . . in Sheet 2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple COUNTIFS() will do it:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$B:$B,$B2,Sheet1!$C:$C,C$1)
```

Comment: I need to use together with ArrayFormula i.e. ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$B:$B,$B2:B,Sheet1!$C:$C,C$1)) which is does not work for countifs.

Comment: You have tagged Excel and Excel does not load arrays. In Excel every cell needs a formula. You put the formula in the first cell then copy over and down.

Comment: I use Google Sheet but It does not allow me to tag as google sheets

Answer (score 0):

Sheet3!B1:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!B:C,"Select B,count(B) group by B pivot C")
```

Add the LEC.Name later.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with just a pivot table:

column= grade
rows=lec. name, lec. id
value= `counta(grade)`

don't forget to select checkbox  `repeat row value` for 1st row